# ERROR: First connection sqldeveloper username and password

Tags: oracle, connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have already installed **sqldeveloper** and i can launch SQLdeveloper client on my Linux Ubuntu 16.04 system.

The problem occurs during the first attempt of the new oracle connection from the client.

**Error returned:**
*"I/O: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection"*

I have already tryed several times to connect at the database but i still missing the *username* and *password*.

***Is it possible to configure username and password for SYS/SYSTEM(or who else) user after installation?***

Answer (score 1):

Full stop.

You don't have a database.

Installing SQL Developer is just giving you a client you can use to work with an existing Oracle Database, which we often refer to as the 'server.'

SQL Developer is not a database.

So you need to get one.

Then you can use SQL Developer.

You have a few options. I talk about them in detail [here](https://medium.com/oracledevs/i-installed-oracle-sql-developer-now-what-71230b9c9303).

Answer (score 0):

> **SQL developer is just like the Key for Safe lock. And Database is the Safe.**

So right now you have the key for Safe but doesn't have Safe.

**Please get the safe first.**

SQL Developer is not the Database. So Installing SQL developer will not give access to DB

Instead SQL Developer is the client side tool to retrieve the data or to do the modification on Database.

To get the database you need to download oracle DB from below link

**http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/oracle12c-windows-3633015.html**